# Array string values get converted to float when adding them to a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

When converting an array to a pandas.DataFrame and adding that dataframe to another, my values get converted to floats even though they are strings.

```
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'Class']
df = pd.read_csv('iris.data', names=names)

X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df.iloc[:,-1:]

y_arr = np.ravel(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_arr, test_size=0.2)

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

final = X_test[['sepal-length', 'sepal-width']]
a = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['Class'])

final['Class'] = a.loc[:, 'Class']
final
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# pass column names as string
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'Class']
# make dict of dtypes
dict_dtypes = {x : 'str'  for x in names}
pd.read_csv('iris.data', dtype=dict_dtypes)
```